# Bootstrap 3 - Grid 2 columns in navbar

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a navigation like this(simplified):

[Codeply Link](http://www.codeply.com/go/wnlotk72Tf)

```
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-6">
                            <li>foo</li>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-6">
                            <li>bar</li>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </ul>
```

In the result the list menu items stack on top of each other in mobile for example:

| foo |
| bar |

My brain tells me it should be this on mobile devices.
| foo | bar |

In the end it should look like [this](http://www.uchicago.edu/) example. (mobile navi)

Comment: Seems correct to me: http://www.bootply.com/Cd8xSuv019 Is this your complete markup? Something else may be affecting your layout.

Answer (score 4):

You can simply use list-items in place of divs like so

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav hidden-lg hidden-md test">
  <li><a href="../navbar-static-top/">asdf</a></li>
  <li><a href="../navbar-static-top/">asdf</a></li>  
</ul>
```

## Update

Your `overflow-child` class enforces a width of 100%

```
.overflow-child {
  /*width: 100%;*/
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  padding-right: 15px;
}
```

Comment: Bang bang!! What do you mean by improperly using divs. and .Container-fuild was not meant to be embeded inside the nav-bar? Please dont make assumptions without stating "you might be wrong" which in this case you are. Look at it being embedded here http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/twitter-bootstrap-tutorial/bootstrap-fluid-layout.php and you can google for more examples.

Comment: Good point @CodingEnthusiast, this was something I clearly wasn't aware of, I removed that part of my answer.

Comment: @KjubE try the code I provided above, it should solve your problem.

Comment: The code above reproduces the same error. I need exactly this: http://www.uchicago.edu/

Comment: Ah I see, you really should have included this in your original question.

Comment: I actually did. I explained it with foo and bar.

Comment: I don't want to argue with you @KjubE everyone is just trying to help you, but when I saw "foo and bar" I didn't get that at all. An actual example in production would have made this much clearer for future reference.

Comment: I didn't mean to be offensive. The childs-overflow width actually ruined it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78716/discussion-between-jeanpier-re-and-kjube).